# Pager in cached ajax view doesn't work

Tags: views, ajax, caching

in drupal 6 I have an ajax view that I cache manually. The following is a block of the function that returns the markup of the view:

```
....

$cache_key = sprintf('user:products_listed:%s', $account->uid);

$products_listed = cache_get($cache_key);

if (! $products_listed) {
  $products_listed = views_embed_view('products_listed', 'default', $account->uid);
  cache_set($cache_key, $products_listed, 'cache', time() + 60 * 60);
} else {
  $products_listed = $products_listed->data;
}

return $products_listed;
```

The view always shows fine, but its ajax pager works fine only when the view shows for the first time (when it is not cached yet). As soon as the view is cached, that is, when I get its content from the cache, the pager doesn't work and it just reloads the page adding the "?page=1" in the URL.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After debugging, I saw that when getting it from the cache, the view's preprocess_views_view is never executed and thereby the ajax view functionality is never "activated". Still trying to make this work.

Comment: You might be better off using Block caching and set it to be per-user.  Take a peek at http://drupal.org/project/blockcache_alter